# What does "du ou de la" mean ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

I was reading an article on lemonde.fr and saw "du ou" used in a sentence. However, I can't figure out how this translates to English.

> Comment fonctionne le mode de désignation du ou de la future première ministre britannique?

Google:
How does the method of appointing the future British Prime Minister work?

How should "du ou" be translated in this sentence?

I checked Collins French-English dictionary and the Academie-Francaise with no success. I did find another [French website](https://www.univ-larochelle.fr/formation/alternance/pour-lentreprise/la-mission-du-ou-de-la-maitresse-dapprentissage/) using "du ou” in the same way, but couldn't find any site that explains this usage.

> Quelles sont les missions du ou de la maitresse d'apprentissage ?

Google: What are the missions of the teacher?

Everything else seems to make sense, but what purpose does "du ou" serve? Is this a fixed expression?

Comment: Quoting the exact sentence and/or giving the link to the article could be helpful, since the meaning may depend on the context. As a general advice - sentences in a foreign language should not be translated word-by-word, but as a whole; often one expresses the same meaning by different means in English and French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Du*** technically means ***de le*** so

> *Désignation **du** ou **de la** future première ministre*.

is a shortcut for:

> *Désignation **du** futur premier ministre **ou de la** future première ministre.*

That's exactly the same with the teacher example.

A literal translation to English is not easy because there are no gendered articles.

I would venture: *The missions of the **he** or **she** teacher* (??)

Comment: Thank you. I have not come across this type of wording in articles before today. Is this more of a modern phrasing being used to support the femininisation of job titles?

Comment: It is not necessarily related to job titles feminization. Older occurrences can be found, e.g. *Cette vente, dont le nom **du ou de la** propriétaire fut tenu secret, produisit 2.882.000 francs.*  A. Frappart, *Les Arts; revue mensuelle des musées, collections, expositions*, avril 1913. *[...] sans faire mention aucune **du ou des** privilèges qu'iceux juges laïques prétendent avoir* J. Severt, *La Somme générale de toutes les excommunications et des cas réservés*, janvier 1621